# How to deactivate grub after fresh installation?

Tags: grub2, windows-8, bootloader

### Short version

I have a system with Windows 8 and in a working but undocumented state and next to it an Ubuntu 12.10 with the Grub2 bootloader, which doesn't recognize Windows correctly. I want to deactivate Grub completely, because if I exit from Grub I automatically get to a bootloader which can load Ubuntu and Windows both without problems.

How can I deactivate Grub completely? What consequences do I face with that decision?

### Long Version

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 64bit next to my OEM Windows 8 onto my freshly bought Lenovo Thinkpad E530. Coming with the installation the Grub2 bootloader starts after activating the machine. The problem is that Grub2 doesn't seem to find the right starting point for the menu point "Start Windows 8" by itself. It points to another partition but if I choose it, nothing happens.

All that is complicated by an undocumented Preconfiguration of the system with 2 other bootloaders already preinstalled. One seems to be a Windows bootloader and another one seems to be a Lenovo bootloader. Maybe both are the same. This is unclear to me.

Now the only option I have at the moment to start Windows after installing Ubuntu 12.10 is to click `c` in Grub2, which brings me to the grub command line, followed by `exit` which as I assume closes the grub completely. Closing grub didn't lead to the expected blackscreen or notion that there is nothing to boot, but it led to the Lenovo bootloader in which I can freely choose between Ubuntu (which boots Ubuntu directly, not Grub again), Windows (which boots Windows as desired) and other options I didn't read yet.

It seems that all the problems would go away with deactivating Grub. So if there are not hard consequences with that I'd like to shut it down that the other bootloader, whatever that might be, gets started automatically.

Comment: Isn't this a UEFI-problem? Can you deactivate the secure boot option for W8 ?

Comment: I already did that. But that's not the problem.

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )